# How to remove :hover effect from a specific element?

Tags: html, css, hover

```
<div class="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Home/index.html"> <i class="fa fa-house"></i>Home</a> </i></li>
            < ul >
</div>

<style>
.menu-bar ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border-inline-end: 2px solid;
  border-block-end: 2px solid;

</style>
```

I want to remove :hover effect from that cdn icon fa fa-house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="menu-bar">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <a href="/Home/index.html">
                Home
             </a>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<style>
    .menu-bar ul li a:hover {
        color: black;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        border-inline-end: 2px solid;
        border-block-end: 2px solid;
    }

    .menu-bar ul li i{
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If anyone is intrested. https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-remove-the-css-hover-behavior-from-an-element.html#:~:text=To%20remove%20the%20CSS%20hover,disable)%20to%20%E2%80%9Cnone%E2%80%9D.

Comment: Then you can't click the icon anymore. Not a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-house"></i><a href="/Home/index.html"> Home</a> </i></li>
    <ul >
```

Just get out `<i>` element (icon) from the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Then you can't click the icon anymore. Not a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-house"><a href="/Home/index.html"> </i>Home</a> </i></li>
        </ul>
   </div>


  <style>
    .menu-bar ul li a:hover {
      color: black;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      border-inline-end: 2px solid;
      border-block-end: 2px solid;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Then you can't click the icon anymore. Not a good user experience.